# The shuffle function in Hands-on programming with R

Tags: r

Here's the question

> Exercise 8.3 (Rewrite shuffle) Rewrite shuffle so that it replaces the copy of deck that lives in the global environment with a shuffled version of DECK, the intact copy of deck that also lives in the global environment. The new version of shuffle should have no arguments and return no output.

And the answer is

```
shuffle <- function(){
    random <- sample(1:52, size = 52)
    assign("deck", DECK[random, ], envir = globalenv())
}
```

My question is

1. What's the point of adding a new object "DECK", and why is it work even we do not define it?
2. Before the shuffle function, we define a deal function.

This is the `deal` function.

```
deal <- function(){
     card <- deck[1, ]
     assign("deck", deck[-1, ], envir = globalenv())
     card
}
```

So after we dealt a card it will remove the card and then save the rest of the cards into "deck"

Therefore when we use the shuffle function, the removed card will appear like

```
    face     suit  value
NA  <NA>     <NA>    NA
17   ten    clubs    10
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure that's what happens? `shuffle` modifies `DECK` to create `deck`, and `deal` modifies `deck`. A `shuffle()` after a `deal()` should give you brand new 52-card shuffle deck with no memory of the `deck` you dealt from.

Comment: What @Gregor-reinstateMonica is trying to say is that first you `shuffle()` the `DECK` and create the shuffled copy `deck`, then you `deal()` one `card` from the `deck`, updating it to become a `deck` with one less card.

Comment: Rewritten: `shuffle2 <- function() {deck <<- DECK[sample(52), ]}`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But should we define "DECK"? Because now it says "object 'DECK' not found"

Comment: Oh. Your question was actually how to make a DECK object?

Comment: Yes, and how those dealt cards go back to the deck after the shuffle function

Comment: Sorry guys I just found out that DECK is just a copy of deck. Then it all makes sense. I get the brand new cards after the shuffle function. Thanks those who helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think DECK is supposed to work even if it is not yet defined. I think this is implicitly referring back to tasks that were described in the text or in a prior question.

I think that DECK is meant to stay as it is and be a static resource of 52 values, whereas `deck` is meant to be the same objects but in a separate object that has a random ordering of its components. The `deal` operation is probably just one step in a multi-step process that results in several, distinct "hand"-objects (perhaps 5 cards each, or two cards and one exposed, depending on the particular type of poker). You would not re-shuffle after dispensing a particular card, but would rather "deal" the next card in (random) sequence.

The author of that assignment is using a non-functional approach. He's creating an object inside a function but "pushing" it outside the function environment where its result is really a side-effect. A couple of the commenters are trying to make it more "functional" by constructing a function that has assignment done after the function operations have been completed. In this case it really doesn't change what is happening, but the strategy proposed by the author is not considered best practices by the R cognoscenti. It can make a difference in some situations, and my advice would be to adopt the functional style if you can.

So you should now define a data structure that can hold multiple "hands" and then write code that keeps track of how many hands, and how many cards have been dealt. You can increment the hand and card counts with each deal operation. Perhaps a matrix?

```
DECK <- expand.grid(Suit =c('S','D','C','H'),
                    Val = c("A","K","Q","J",10:2) )
# insert the functions you already have.
Suitable control  ... perhaps nested `for`-loops? or nested `sapply` loops?
 {
 hand[i,j] <- deal()
 }
```

Has such a process been illustrated on SO before? Perhaps, even likely. Do a search on "[r] deck deal cards":
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+cards+deck+deal

Comment: Thanks for your response! I just start learning R less than 2 weeks, so I probably can't fully understand your answer. And it turns out DECK is defined in the previous text. It's just a copy of deck. My mistake :(  Still, your information is useful for me.

Comment: @42- Wouldn't the expand.grid qualifies as a common general question.

Comment: I suppose. It wasn’t clear to me at the beginning that building the DECK object was the barrier. I initially thought it was difficulty understanding why there might be a need for a DECK and a separate “deck”.